# require bigdecimal loaderror ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, compiler-errors, irb

I have a very frustrating problem. I have ubuntu 12.04 on my home machine with ruby 1.8.7 and I just barely completed a project that compiles and runs perfectly on my home machine but when I ported it to my universities lab (which it must compile on for me to get a grade, they are also running ruby 1.8.7) I get the following error:

```
`require': no such file to load -- bigdecimal (LoadError)
```

The class I'm trying to require is the `BigDecimal` class which I need for larger floating point precision for some logarithmic calculations for my project.
Can anybody help me decipher why this would be an issue? I thought the BigDecimal class was included with the ruby core libraries for 1.8.7? Am I missing something here?
EDIT: Code being compiled.

```
  `#this is the language model generator
    require "trainer"
    require "bigdecimal"

class Model
    attr_accessor :frequency_tables

def initialize(trainer, test_file)
@trainer = trainer
@frequency_tables = []
@frequency_tables[0] = trainer.corpus
@frequency_tables[1] = trainer.freq
@frequency_tables[2] = trainer.bifreq
@frequency_tables[3] = trainer.trifreq
@frequency_tables[4] = trainer.word_count()
@frequency_tables[5] = trainer.vocab_count()
end

def unigram_count(string)
string.upcase!
return @frequency_tables[1][string]
end
def bigram_count(string)
string.upcase!
return @frequency_tables[2][string]
end
def trigram_count(string)
string.upcase!
return @frequency_tables[3][string]
end

def round(float)
return ((float * 10000).round.to_f) / 10000 
end

def process_unigram(sentence)
probability = BigDecimal.new("1") 
sen_arr = sentence.split(" ")
sen_arr.each { |word|
#  binding.pry
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new(unigram_count(word).to_s()) / BigDecimal.new(@frequency_tables[4].to_s())) 
}
unless probability.eql? 0
    val= ((Math.log(probability)/Math.log(2))) 
    return retval = round(val)  
end
return "undefined" 
end

def process_bigram(sentence)
probability = BigDecimal.new("1")
sen_arr = sentence.split(" ")
for i in (0..(sen_arr.length-1))
  unless i == 0
  denom = BigDecimal.new(unigram_count(sen_arr[i-1]).to_s())/BigDecimal.new(@frequency_tables[4].to_s())
    unless denom.eql? 0
      probability *= (BigDecimal.new(bigram_count(sen_arr[i-1]+" "+sen_arr[i]).to_s()) / BigDecimal.new(@frequency_tables[4].to_s()))/denom  
     else
      probability = 0
     end
  else
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new(bigram_count("PHI "+sen_arr[i]).to_s()) / BigDecimal.new(@frequency_tables[4].to_s())) / (BigDecimal.new(unigram_count("PHI").to_s())/BigDecimal.new(@frequency_tables[4].to_s()))   
  end
end
unless probability.eql? 0
    val= ((Math.log(probability)/Math.log(2))) 
    retval = round(val) 
    return retval
end
return "undefined"
end

def process_trigram(sentence)
probability = BigDecimal.new("1")
sen_arr = sentence.split(" ")
for i in (0..(sen_arr.length-1))
  if i >= 2
  denom = (BigDecimal.new(bigram_count(sen_arr[i-2]+" "+sen_arr[i-1]).to_s()))
      unless denom.eql? 0
      probability *= (BigDecimal.new(trigram_count(sen_arr[i-2]+" "+sen_arr[i-1]+" "+sen_arr[i]).to_s()))/denom   
      else
    probability *= 0
      end
  elsif i == 1
  denom = (BigDecimal.new(bigram_count("PHI "+sen_arr[i-1]).to_s()))
      unless denom.eql? 0
      probability *= (BigDecimal.new(trigram_count("PHI "+sen_arr[i-1]+" "+sen_arr[i]).to_s()))/denom  
      else
      probability = 0
      end
  else
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new(trigram_count("PHI PHI "+sen_arr[i]).to_s())) / (BigDecimal.new(unigram_count("PHI").to_s()))   
  end
end
unless probability.eql? 0 
    val= ((Math.log(probability)/Math.log(2))) 
    retval = round(val) 
    return retval
end
return "undefined"
end

def process_smooth_bigram(sentence)
probability = BigDecimal.new("1")
sen_arr = sentence.split(" ")
for i in (0..(sen_arr.length-1))
  unless i == 0
  bigram_c = bigram_count(sen_arr[i-1]+" "+sen_arr[i])+1
  ugram_c = unigram_count(sen_arr[i-1])+@frequency_tables[5]
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new(bigram_c.to_s()))/(BigDecimal.new(ugram_c.to_s()))   
  else
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new((bigram_count("PHI "+sen_arr[i])+1).to_s())) / (BigDecimal.new((unigram_count("PHI")+@frequency_tables[5]).to_s()))   
  end
end
unless probability.eql? 0
    val= ((Math.log(probability)/Math.log(2))) 
    retval = round(val) 
    return retval
end
return "undefined"
end

def process_smooth_trigram(sentence)
probability = BigDecimal.new("1")
sen_arr = sentence.split(" ")
for i in (0..(sen_arr.length-1))
  if i >= 2
  denom = (BigDecimal.new((bigram_count(sen_arr[i-2]+" "+sen_arr[i-1])+@frequency_tables[5]).to_s()))
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new((trigram_count(sen_arr[i-2]+" "+sen_arr[i-1]+" "+sen_arr[i])+1).to_s()))/denom   
  elsif i == 1
  denom = (BigDecimal.new((bigram_count("PHI "+sen_arr[i-1])+@frequency_tables[5]).to_s()))
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new((trigram_count("PHI "+sen_arr[i-1]+" "+sen_arr[i])+1).to_s()))/denom  
  else
  probability *= (BigDecimal.new((trigram_count("PHI PHI "+sen_arr[i])+1).to_s())) / (BigDecimal.new((unigram_count("PHI")+@frequency_tables[5]).to_s()))   
  end
end
unless probability.eql? 0 
    val= ((Math.log(probability)/Math.log(2))) 
    retval = round(val) 
    return retval
end
return "undefined"
end
end`
```

Comment: Where is your `require` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the machines on the lab I was using had multiple versions of Ruby installed on them without my knowledge. I think IRB was using the info from the other versions and thus I was able to use bigdecimal without using it with just the Ruby command. After using the other version of Ruby that was installed it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Probably a syntax error, add some code and I'll update.

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > require 'bigdecimal'
 => true 

ruby-1.8.7-p334 :002 >  BigDecimal("1.0e+25") - BigDecimal("9999999999999999900000000.0")
 => #<BigDecimal:10035f970,'0.1E9',9(45)>
```

Comment: when i go into irb i can do require 'bigdecimal' as well and I get true, then I can also manipulate the class. WTF?! I'll edit in some code to my original post.

Comment: What happens if you copy/paste your model directly into `irb`? Does it recognize it or does it also error?